# SSE Emitter passing error in Angular Component

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to implement SSE (Server Side Event Emitter) in Spring Boot.The application runs fine in browser but when I call the application in angular code it finally errors out.
My Spring Boot code is from https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/rest/spring-async-controller-sseemitter/

```
@RestController
public class DataSetController {
 
      private final DataSetService dataSetService;
 
      public DataSetController(DataSetService dataSetService) {
            this.dataSetService = dataSetService;
      }
 
      @GetMapping("/emit-data-sets")
      public SseEmitter fetchData2() 
      {
            SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
 
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 
            executor.execute(() -> 
            {
                  List<DataSet> dataSets = dataSetService.findAll();
                  try {
                        for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
 
                              randomDelay();
                              emitter.send(dataSet);
                        }
 
                        emitter.complete();
 
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                        emitter.completeWithError(e);
                  }
            });
            executor.shutdown();
            return emitter;
      }
 
      private void randomDelay() {
            try {
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
      }
}
```

My Angular Code is from this link https://bartoszgajda.com/2019/12/22/angular-and-server-sent-events-sse/

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private sseService: SseService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sseService
      .getServerSentEvent("http://localhost:8082/raw")
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data),
       error => console.log("The code errors out here")
       );
  }
}
```

The response comes in the console as shown below

[image]

Please help me why is the code erroring out in the end? The server code runs fine in the browser,Is this a issue with Angular or Spring Boot?

Comment: is emitter.completeWithError(e); get called on the server?

Comment: No It is not getting called

Comment: could you try doing the same, but without executors. just emit everything you want in the emitter and return it

Comment: I tried it still the same error.It gets executed four times and error's out in angular

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the link mentioned here

https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/10/09/kraken-server-sent-events-reactive/#sse-and-angular